# how to tell sendmail to do masquerading before dkim?

Tags: sendmail, dkim, opendkim

Problem: Using

```
:
:
dnl # opendkim
include(`/etc/mail/m4/opendkim.m4')dnl

dnl # ClamAV milter
include(`/etc/mail/m4/clamav-milter.m4')dnl

dnl # Masquerading options
MASQUERADE_AS(`example.com')dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(`example.com')dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(`example.de')dnl

FEATURE(`always_add_domain')dnl
FEATURE(`allmasquerade')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_entire_domain')dnl
:
:
```

in sendmail.mc opendkim adds a signature to the header, and next sendmail changes the header for masquerading, making the dkim signature invalid. Not reasonable.

How can I tell sendmail to apply all the "masquerade" options and features **before** adding a signature via opendkim?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working through that same problem.  I don't have a working config yet, but it looks like the **ReplaceRules** setting in **opendkim.conf** is the thing to use.

From the man page:

> **ReplaceRules (string)** Specifies a file containing a list  of  text  replacement  rules that are applied to the message header fields to
> replace certain content expected to be changed as  the  message
> passes  through local  MTAs.   This  can be used to accommodate
> expected changes such as are made to From: fields by MTA  "masquerade"
> features.

**Edit:**  Version 2.11.0-0.1 in the EPEL repo has the **ReplaceRules** feature marked *experimental*, not compiled into the distribution bundle, so not easily available.  I abandoned the idea of compiling my own copy.  Much easier (at least in my case) to have Sendmail rewrite headers during intake - in "submit.mc" - before OpenDKIM ever sees them.

i.e., the **sendmail.mc** and **submit.mc** config files *both* include stuff like this:

```
MASQUERADE_AS(`mydomain.com')
FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(`notherhost.mydomain.com')
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN_FILE(`/my/awesome/hostlist')
```